# Automatic scaling not working on Azure Germany

Tags: azure, azure-autoscaling-block

I am working on Microsoft Azure Germany and having issues with the automatic scaling option for app services. I selected the S1 app service plan but cannot select anything else but manually scalling. This plan should normally include the automatic scaling. Did anyone experience something similar? I read that azure germany has some problems with some etablished features of the "regular" azure version.

best regards

Peter

Comment: Hi Peter,

I was just here to ask exactly the same question! Same issue here... did you find something out in the meantime? I would say - let us open a support ticket, but I fear that will take weeks or months (if we ever get an answer).

Comment: Hey @mavo, ic already got an answer. Its not supported in the current version of the Azure Germany Cloud. The feature support between these two clouds is different but the documentation does not differentiate. best regards

Comment: Unbelievable... thanks a lot for the information!